# Batch - set argument as variable without resolving eventual variable inside argument

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line-arguments

I am trying to find a way to issue I have faced with my script. I have simulated my issue in short script so no long code will have to be read.

Basically what I want/need to achieve is to start my batch with argument and work with argument the same way as-is defined by script user, but replace percent signs with escape character followed by percent sign (% > ^%). But issue come up if argument contain some existing variable like %date%

Here is the short version of my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "x=%~1"
set "y=!x:%%=^^%%!"
echo %y%
```

Argument can contain anything, but can also look as follow:

```
script.bat "this should be just plain text - %date%"
```

My expected output from the batch script would be like:

```
this should be just plain text - ^%date^%
```

However it seems that variable is resolved immediately and though percent signs are not even being escaped, since it can't find any. If argument does not contain any variable it works well, but this way output look like this:

```
this should be just text - Wed 01/15/2014
```

I am trying to avoid any additional scripting language usage (like VBS) and usage of any other application, but rather will have VBS way e.g. than nothing.
Any help, assistance or hint how to achieve this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%date%` variable is being expanded as soon as you call `script.bat` - so in your script `%1` will already have the expanded `%date%` variable. You have to add the carets when calling the script -

```
script.bat "this should be just plain text - ^%date^%"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought so, but was just hoping to find some workaround to mitigate this need.